# Prevent Chrome from warning about a missing autocomplete attribute

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome-devtools

In my app I have a "change password" form which requires a user to enter their current password and their new password (twice).

The purpose of entering the current password is a security measure, e.g. if a user steps away from their desk, it prevents someone else from changing their password and gaining control of their account.

For this reason, I absolutely do not want this field to be autocompleted. However, if I don't specify an `autocomplete` attribute, I get the following warning in Chrome's dev console

> [DOM] Input elements should have autocomplete attributes (suggested: "current-password"): (More info: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/create-amazing-password-forms/) <input id=​"current-password" type=​"password">​

If I add an attribute `autocomplete="current-password"` the warning no longer appears, but the field is filled automatically with the user's current password, which defeats the very purpose of this field.

How can I prevent this field from being filled automatically without getting a warning in the Chrome console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the value **off** in the autocomplete attribute.
For example: `autocomplete="off"`

Read more about it on [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete).